# Load specific URL after pushing from UITableView

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

I create UITableView and I have 3 cells , so each cell should push to DetailViewController to load specific URL . On detailViewController I have UIWebView that load url after user select a cell of tableView , But I don't know how can I do this things  ! . Here is my code

.h:

```
    #import "webController.h"

@class webController;
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource> {

    NSArray *list;
    webController *webcontroller;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) IBOutlet NSArray *list;

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (!webcontroller) {
    webcontroller = [[webController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    webcontroller.navigationItem.title = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webcontroller animated:YES];


}else {
    webcontroller.navigationItem.title=[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webcontroller animated:YES];  


}


}
```

Comment: do you mean that how to do this thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to what iHS said:

The best way (in my opinion) would be to have two NSArray's. One to display the name (google, apple, yahoo) and then one to store the specific URL.

So you could do something like this

in .h:

```
NSArray *urlArray;
```

and then in the .m:
(modified iHS's code)

```
if (!webcontroller) {
     webcontroller = [[webController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}
 webcontroller.navigationItem.title=[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
webcontroller.strUrl = [urlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //Load the url at the specific index in "urlArray"
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webcontroller animated:YES];
```

Post any questions below ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by various methods. The simpler and best would be to create a property in your webController class

`@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *strUrl`

and then synthesize it by using

`@synthesize strUrl` in your webController.m

Now in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (!webcontroller) {
    webcontroller = [[webController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
}

 webcontroller.navigationItem.title=[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 webcontroller.strUrl = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:webcontroller animated:YES];  


 }
```

Then use this strUrl to load the page in webview. I hope it helps

Comment: thank you , but my problem is I can't understand how can detect user selecting cell to load webPage on webViewController ! for example `cell 0 = www.google.com cell 1 = www.yahoo.com`

Comment: @Mc.Lover: i guess you are storing all the urls in list array. dont u?

Comment: No ! I did not store any url ! ` NSArray *menuList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"google", @"apple" , @"yahoo" , nil];
    self.list = menuList;
    [menuList release];`

Comment: You need to store the urls in an another array. Or alternativly, you have to append strings using [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.%@".com",[menuList objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]

Comment: sorry I am new to iphone sdk ,, would please help me more ? or write the code ? because i didn't get my answer